# OpenCL build: advantage of stringying kernel code

Tags: opencl

I am currently in the process of distributing an OpenCL program (online compilation).

Now my kernel code is in a `*.cl` file, which is read during kernel building. I think that is also possible to convert the kernel source code into string literals, that can be read directly instead of the `*.cl` for the same purpose.

My question is: what would be the advantage of stringfying the kernel code?

Comment: there could be parts like `@replace_me@` and one can replace them with dynamically changed values and re-compile same code with different parameters such as local array size (local array size must be constant so you can re-compile whenever you need a different size for local arrays). `__local float data[@replace_me_@];`

Comment: I recommend you put the code in a string in the code. It is much easier to use than opening a file.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: wouldn't it be better to use compiler defines for transfer those constant primitives (`-DSIZE=NUM`)?.

Comment: @DarkZeros: could you please explain more why using a string is much easier than opening a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages:

- No need to deal with IO. If you have to support multiple file systems, this can be a pain (Windows, Linux, etc...).
- Easier for the user, the executable is only 1 file.
- You may have problems if somebody edits the .cl file.
- Easier to compile and ship.

Example:

```
const char *KernelSource = "\n" \
"__kernel void square(                     \n" \
"   __global float* input,                 \n" \
"   __global float* output,                \n" \
"   const unsigned int count)              \n" \
"{                                         \n" \
"   int i = get_global_id(0);              \n" \
"   if(i < count)                          \n" \
"       output[i] = input[i] * input[i];   \n" \
"}                                         \n";

program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &KernelSource, NULL, &err);
```

Comment: A disadvantage is that if you use strings, you have to recompile your host program whenever you change your kernel source. If you have your kernel on the file, it can be compiled independently.